# Require approval from all owners before deleting repo

Tags: git, github

I have multiple owners in my public GitHub repo. [From the docs](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/) it appears that any individual owner can go rogue and delete the entire repo from existence. I'd like to prevent that from happening.

Is there any way to set up Git permissions such that deleting the repo requires the approval of ALL owners? Or have I misread the docs and that's actually how it is already?

Making myself the sole owner is not a viable solution, as I want to prevent myself (or an unauthorized user of my account) from having this power, too.

Comment: I don't believe this is possibly unfortunately. That's typically why you want to limit the number of owners.

Comment: Don't forget that git is a 'distributed' SCM; one of its greatest strengths.
So even if the instance of the repo on GitHub is removed there should be many other copies among the other contributors.
Originally, long before The Internet, git repositories were simply shared from  one machine to another.  Although they have made it much easier, GitHub is SIMPLY another such computer.

Comment: @ThomParkin Excellent point. My main concern, though, and the big advantage of GitHub is the ancillary information stored on there, like the Issue Tracking and Wiki. Of course, I'll bet that GitHub can restore a repo after it's been deleted but it'd be nice to have protections to prevent it in the first place.